# Can't boot from USB (Centos7, Samsung series 5 ultrabook)

Tags: linux, boot, usb, installation, centos

As in the title, I've got a series 5 ultrabook, am currently running Ubunutu 16.04, and am attempting to install CentOS7. I've written the iso to a usb, and, as suggested in various resources, disabled fast-boot and secure boot, have attempted booting with UEFI and CSM, to no avail. I've even tried writing to a different USB, loading a USB with ubuntu, changing the boot order, using different disk-writing programs... Every time, it simply boots up, sometimes I select the boot device, and theres a blank screen for about a minute, before just loading up ubuntu like normal.

PLEASE HELP! Kind of need this for a uni unit.